# What would be one word for an honorary address, like "Your Highness"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do I call the address I make to distinguished people whom I cannot address by there given names.
For example, I have to call a Knighted Man with the address "Sir".
In Royalty this is termed as style/honorific.

Is there any generic word for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic term is ***honorific***:

> - A title, phrase, or grammatical form conveying respect, used especially when addressing a social superior.

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/honorific)

> - The most common honorifics in modern English are usually placed immediately before a person's name. Honorifics which can be used (both as style and as form of address) include, in the case of a man, "Mr" (irrespective of marital status), and in the case of a woman the honorific will depend on her marital status...,
> - Other honorifics may denote the honored person's occupation, for instance "Doctor", "Esquire", "Captain", "Coach", "Officer", "Reverend" for all clergy and/or "Father" (for a Catholic, Eastern Orthodox, Oriental Orthodox, or Anglican Christian priest), or Professor.[a] Holders of an academic Doctorate such as PhD are addressed as "Doctor" (abbreviated Dr).

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific)